# echo names and values of all env variables that start with "nlu_setting"

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, variable

I am looking for a way to echo names and values of all env variables that start with nlu_setting, so the output might look like:

```
nlu_setting_json=true
nlu_setting_global=0
nlu_setting_bar=foo
```

does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Environment variables?  Or shell variables?  The difference is important, as it rules in/out several answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
for var in "${!nlu_setting_@}"; do
    printf '%s=%s\n' "$var" "${!var}"
done
```

The expansion `${!nlu_setting_@}` is a `bash`-specific expansion that returns a list of variable names matching a particular prefix. Here we use it to ask for all names that start with the string `nlu_setting_`.  We loop over these names and output the name along with the value of that variable.

We get the value of the variable using variable indirection (`${!var}`).

Comment: do you think this is better than the compgen solution?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I would say that it will be more efficient as it's not calling `grep`. Your solution would also pick up variable names that contain `nlu_setting_` anywhere, not just at the start of the variable name (due to the non-anchored regular expression that you are using).

Comment: ah yes good point

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the answers to this question, I came up with this:

```
   compgen -A variable nlu_setting_ | while read v; do
            echo "$v = ${!v}";
   done
```

it seems to work. Never heard of the compgen command, but if it's universal bash built-in, it should be all good..

Answer (score 4):

Both older answers are good, yet I came with my own:

```
env | grep ^nlu_setting_ | while read kv; do echo "$kv"; done
```

Doesn't distinguish for key and value, and uses grep, but that's exactly what I wanted - only env variables, only starting with proper prefix. Maybe someone will find this variant useful.

Comment: Why do you include ```⁠ | while read kv; do echo "$kv"; done```?  That adds nothing to `env | grep '^nlu_setting_'` except a waste of resources.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add much to the answers from kusalananda (for bash) or from stephane (for zsh) other than the addition of `grep`. Both previous answers give exactly what you wanted so why change a good thing?

Comment: @doneal24: To be fair, this *does* appear to be the only correct answer. All the others list shell variables, which are a superset of environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to do the same in `zsh`, the `-m` option of `typeset` can be used to list the variables that match a pattern:

```
$ typeset -m 'nlu_setting_*'
nlu_setting_1=scalar
nlu_setting_2=( some array )
nlu_setting_3=( [associative]=array [now]=some )
```

To include the information of type:

```
$ typeset -pm 'nlu_setting_*'
typeset nlu_setting_1=scalar
typeset -a nlu_setting_2=( some array )
typeset -A nlu_setting_3=( [associative]=array [now]=some )
```

To list parameters whose name matches a pattern:

```
$ print -rC1 ${(kM)parameters:#nlu_setting_*}
nlu_setting_1
nlu_setting_2
nlu_setting_3
```

The *values* of the `$parameters` special associative arrays is the type of the variable. So to list only scalar ones for instance:

```
$ print -rC1 ${(kM)parameters[(R)scalar]:#nlu_setting_*}
nlu_setting_1
```

(using `R`everse subscripting).

To print the corresponding name and value, beside using `typeset -m`, you can do:

```
$ for v (${(kM)parameters[(R)scalar]:#nlu_setting_*}) printf '%s=%q\n' $v ${(P)v}
nlu_setting_1=scalar
```