# Listing shell variables with a fixed prefix

Tags: shell, variable

I've looked this up and can't find an answer, I apologise in advance if it's been previously asked.

I'm using shell on FreeBSD (`/bin/sh`) and I want to dump to stdout all shell (**not** environment) variables starting with `_myvar_`. The closest I can get is `set | grep '^_myvar_'` but that only dumps the first line of multiline variables (some will be multiline and I need them in full), and it could be error prone in pathological edge cases such as a string containing "*myvar*" that happens to line-break just before that part.

if I could list just variable names (not values), then I could filter within a `do...read...while` and get the values one at a time just for vars with matching names, but I can't find a way to do this. I also can't filter the full output, because there is no deterministic way to tell whether an output line contains a continuation or a new variable, that doesn't have edge-case issues with strings containing `_myvar_`,  `=` or `newline (\n)` characters, or possibly, trailing spaces. I don't want to modify the environment, because the code is included in other code and the environment has to be stable for it.

It isn't a problem for the output/list to include any matching environment variables if that helps (if any exist - it's extremely unlikely they will)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [Environment variables? Or shell variables? The difference is important.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460462/#comment837420_460462)

Comment: Shell. They show up in `set` but not in `printenv` when using `/bin/sh`, and cease to exist when the script finally exits. Question updated to be clearer.

Comment: In ksh or Bash, you could use `"${!_myvar_@}"`, though that would still include exported variables

Comment: @ilkkachu -But the shell in the question explicitly **isn't** ksh or bash. Do you know a way to do it in a more traditional type of shell like the one involved in the question?

Comment: @Stilez, yep. You could pick the variable names from the `set` output, you might just get some extras if some variables had values that would look like something `set` would output for another variable, but you could check those later. Though indirect references to the variables would also be easier in Bash or ksh, as you  wouldn't need to use any `eval` trickery. So yeah, I'd suggest at least looking at using some other shell, one that would be more suited to that job...

Comment: I don't have that choice. It has to fit into existing code on a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `set` builtin of FreeBSD `sh` outputs in a format that is suitable for reinput to the shell, you can do:

```
out() case $1 in (_myvar_*) printf '%s\n' "${1%%=*}"; esac
eval "$(set | sed 's/^/out /')"
```

That is prefix each line of the output of `set` with `"out "` and have that evaluated as shell code (where `out` is a function that prints the substring of its first argument up to the first `=`).

`sed` would also insert `"out "` in the content of multiline variable, but that would still be included in the argument that our `out` function receives and past the first `=`, so in the part we're not displaying.

For instance, on a `set` output like:

```
TERM=xterm
USER=stephane
_myvar_foo='line1
line2
line3'
```

We would be evaluating:

```
out TERM=xterm
out USER=stephane
out _myvar_foo='line1
out line2
out line3'
```

But that's still fine as `out` is only called 3 times for those 3 variables.

To print both variable name and value:

```
out() case $1 in (_myvar_*)
  eval 'printf "name: \"%s\" value: \"%s\"\n" "${1%%=*}" "${'"${1%%=*}"'}"'
esac
eval "$(set | sed 's/^/out /')"
```

Note that it only outputs *variables*, not other types of parameters like `$-`, positional parameters...

That approach only works for `sh` implementations where `set` only outputs *scalar* variables (won't work for arrays or associative arrays or compound variables, where `out var=(x)` becomes a syntax error). Those shells that have other variable types often also have better introspection features.

In `zsh`:

```
typeset -pm '_myvar_*'
```

or for the names only

```
echo $parameters[(I)_myvar_*]
```

In `bash`:

```
v=("${!_myvar_@}"); ((${#v[@]})) && typeset -p -- "${v[@]}"
echo "${!_myvar_@}"
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm assuming out() is a normal function definition without the more common `out() {\n ...CODE...\n}\n` around the function's code? (The rest makes sense). Also how robust is this against pathological values/newlines, or is that purely down to the function executed and any escaping/substitutions done within `eval`?

Comment: @Stilez, yes definition a function is sticking `fname()` in front of a command, though with some shells like `bash` or `yash` that only works for _compound commands_ (some other shells also have issues when the command is not a compound one and has redirection which is probably POSIX only requires compound commands to be supported). In any case, a `case ... esac` like `{...;}` are _compound commands_.

Comment: @Stilez, it should be robust as long as `set` is correct, as long as it outputs something that can indeed be used as input to the shell as it's meant to. You can't do that with _any_ sh though. Not with `bash` for instance where the arrays would break that.

Comment: The values should in theory be strings only - although one can't prevent a user from defining additional variables otherwise (but it's unlikely and someone who defines pathological vars with names matching internal/private ones, probably deserves the outcome ;-) ). If I have to switch to bash at any time, there are probably solutions for that shell. But at the moment, it looks like it has to be the traditional /bin/sh not bash. I'll check if it works nicely when home :) thanks

Comment: I didn't know globbing (or equivalent) worked on variable names, to allow all variable names matching `_myvar_*` to be iterated/traversed in a `case` statement, though. Can you comment on that part, because that looks like the 'magic' in your code snippet, and I've never seen that done before.

Comment: @Stilez, see if the edit makes it clearer

Comment: So the magic in `sh`, is that if each line is prefixed by some text that resembles a command, only those lines which define a variable result in a line which would be executable; the rest just modify a variable value being passed within an arg, in a previous line. By also defining a function named for the ^* text we inserted, we can capture each variable as a single arg (`$1` will be of the form `name=arbitrary junk`), use `sed` to filter out the variable names, and either get the values by regex (reversing the `sed` on the junk) or using `set var-name`. If correct - that's sneaky! And clever!

Comment: Possible correction - should it be `case $1 in _myvar_*)`? ShellCheck seems to think there shouldn't be a "(" character.

Comment: both `case $1 in _myvar_*)` and `case $1 in (_myvar_*)` are standard `sh`. The latter was not supported by the Bourne shell. I prefer the former as I find it more legible and it helps with `vi`'s parens matching. I don't see that shellcheck complains about it (tried with `case $1 in (a) echo a; esac` with a `#! /bin/sh -` shebang at shellcheck.net. Possibly you have an older version of shellcheck.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following simplification of @StéphaneChazelas solution, because I didn't need more. Posting it below in case it helps anyone. But Stéphane found the answer, this is just a modded version of it, nothing more.

```
#!/bin/sh

get_vars() {
  if printf '%s' "$1" | grep -qE '^_myvar_'; then
    printf '%s\n' "$1" | sed 's/^get_vars //'
  fi
}

eval "$( set | sed 's/^/get_vars /' )"
```

The `eval` call prefixes each line, but because of the way `set` outputs its values, it actually creates a single command `get_vars VARNAME=VALUE` for each variable. Evaluating this executes the commands. Then each time it's called, `get_vars` checks if the variable which is captured in the current line matches the required regex, and if so, removes the `"get_vars "` prefix from any second and further lines, and displays the result.

Comment: Note that it may _look_ simpler, but it's a lot more expensive as it forks 4 processes and runs two external utilities for each variable (compared to none in my approach). It has however the benefit of giving an output that is suitable for reinput to the shell. replacing `grep` with a `case` statement would improve performance.

Comment: Learn every day. Thank you for an excellent answer + comments!